# Simulating orbits using Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, simulations

I've been having a go at programming an orbital simulator from scratch (without using any existing libraries) using the formula below to find the acceleration first for particle A and then for particle B towards each other.

$$F = \frac{m_Am_BG}{r^2}$$

$$a_{AB} = \frac{m_BG}{r^2}$$
$$a_{BA} = \frac{m_AG}{r^2}$$

The particles have masses: $m_A = 300\times10^{23}, m_B = 10\times10^{23}$

This produces what looks to be almost a correct orbit with the lighter particle B orbiting around particle A however particle A does not move in an ellipse rather a half ellipse before continuing upwards with another half ellipse and so on. This can be seen in the image below:

[image: Orbits issue image]

The time step does not seem to be an issue as I've adjusted that and it made no difference, it is currently set to $0.000001\mathrm{s}$. I'm not sure as to what might cause this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to CompSci.

Comment: @jinawee But the major part is related to the Physics surely? I doubt I'd be able to get as good an answer on SO as this is entirely Physics related.

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture, but is the weirdness really only happening at the edges? Are your initial conditions such that there is an upward momentum of the system?

Comment: @BMS Yes, particle B has an upward velocity of $70000\mathrm{m/s}$

Comment: So the system has initial momentum upward, and the center of mass is also traveling upward? Sounds realistic to me.

Comment: You may want to check your algorithm with [my algorithm](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99116/25301)

Comment: @BMS That's a good point, I somehow managed to overlook that entirely. Thanks. Is it possible to produce a stable orbit with this method though?

Comment: @KyleKanos I use an algorithm very similar to yours, it does not make use of the Runge-Kutta methods though.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98447/what-are-the-correct-initial-conditions-for-the-moon-in-a-simulation